# Is there a way to Open an App just by its Name in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I'm making an "Advanced Virtual Assistant" by using Python and I want to be able to run any app on the PC with just entering its name. Something likes:

```
i = input("What App Do You Want To Open?:  ")
d = getDirectory(i)
os.startfile(d)
```

Now I can set this up manually for some apps by getting their directory but it won't be for every app so its not what I need. Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: You will either need to pull the registry key at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`, or use the the win32 module to pull the list of `Win32_Product` classes https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/aa394378(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: can you give me an example on how to use the registry key for this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way, but you could use something like [winapps](https://github.com/rominf/winapps) which will get you the install directory of the program if it exists. However, the hard part is knowing which file will execute the program.

You could use [wmi](https://github.com/tjguk/wmi) to fetch the location by passing in the info from winapps; similar to this [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28569573/11916773) but that may be out of date so have a look through the [/docs/](https://github.com/tjguk/wmi/tree/master/docs).

Comment: I think WMI might work. I'll test it out. Can I get some sample code?

Comment: I linked to another answer which has a sample, the documentation also has plenty of samples

Comment: Can you please read what I posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62064645/is-there-a-way-to-open-an-app-just-by-its-name-in-python/62091922#62091922

Answer (score 0):

From Lucan's answer, I got this code:

```
import wmi
w = wmi.WMI()
for p in w.Win32_Product():
    if 'Box, Inc.' == p.Vendor and p.Caption and 'Box Sync' in p.Caption:
        print 'Installed {}'.format(p.Version)
```

Sorry but I couldn't figure it out, Where exactly does the app name go in this?

Answer (score 0):

There are many good tools to do this already.

Here is an common solution you may try implement it:

- Scan or record apps on your PC and store records in database or formated file. (e.g. registry / program files / other folders )
- Map app name, description, caption or etc to the app executable path.(read executable information with `wmi` or other way as the other answers described.)
- Try find the entered text in the fields.
- (if you want nature language matching, that's another story.)
- Use Python `subprocess` or other function/lib to run the executable of the record you just found.

Comment: I would do that, but as I said, I am building a virtual assistant, one capable of operating at any device. Storing the data might work for me, but it won't work as well on other devices

Comment: yes, you are right. just wanted to provider a common idea.

Answer (score 0):

I've written the below which uses [`winapps`](https://github.com/rominf/winapps) as suggested in my previous answer. This implementation has many limitations, such as it only works for programs installed for all users. However, you could alter this code to use another way of getting the install location and use `getPossibleExePaths` to get the executables. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/908907/11916773) gives some alternative ways which may be better than `winapps`.

```
import os
import winapps
import subprocess

def getPossibleExePaths(appPath):
    if not appPath:
        raise Exception("App Path cannot be None")
    pattern = appPath + ":*exe"
    try:
        returned = subprocess.check_output(['where', pattern]).decode('utf-8')
        listOfPaths = filter(None, returned.split(os.linesep))
        return [i.strip() for i in list(listOfPaths)]
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        raise Exception(f"Error getting path for '{appPath}'")

def getAppPath(appName):
    for app in winapps.search_installed(appName):
        installPath = str(app.install_location)
        if installPath and installPath != "None":
            return installPath
    return None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(getPossibleExePaths(getAppPath('Chrome')))
```

This code utilises Window's `where` command so this will not work cross-platform.

However, **please note** that `getPossibleExePaths` will return a list of executable paths and not necessarily the executable that will launch the process. You'll need to figure out how your program will deal with that, there's no easy way to separate out an `uninstaller.exe` from `launchApp.exe`. You could, of course, match up the uninstall location that `winapps` provides and exclude it from the returned list but that doesn't solve the issue that it **might not be the launch executable**.

I hope that helps you

Comment: This works for the most part, and perfectly opens up brave and chrome with just their name. For some reason, its not compatible with all apps as my other applications like discord, fortnite fail to run through this.

Comment: As I said, it'll only work for apps installed for all users; that's just a limitation of winapps. You don't have to use winapps though, you can modify it to use your own function for getting the install locations.